# Почему 301 редирект в WordPress уходит в цикл?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Суть следующая, на сайте (WordPress: https://xn----7sbbf6ab7ab4ael4cr4b1dj.xn--p1ai/) есть некоторые страницы, на которые настроен редирект одна из них: https://xn----7sbbf6ab7ab4ael4cr4b1dj.xn--p1ai/dachnaya-amnistiya-zemelnogo-uchastka-oformit-sobstvennost-registraciya.
Данная ссылка возвращает ошибку `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. Гуглил, что проблема в htaccess (ссылка на .htaccess https://pastebin.com/fqMXWubZ строка 685).

По сути редирект работает, он перенаправляет с `/dachnaya-amnistiya-zemelnogo-uchastka-oformit` на `/dachnaya-amnistiya-zemelnogo-uchastka-oformit-sobstvennost-registraciya` однако после редиректа ведет себя так, будто там есть повторный редирект на самого себя (т.е. зацикливается) и выдает `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`.

Также гугл выдавал проблемы связанные с плагинами, список плагинов:

1. Accelerated Mobile Pages;
2. Advanced Custom Fields;
3. Advanced Custom Fields: Repeater Field;
4. Breadcrumb NavXT;
5. Comet Cache Pro;
6. Custom Permalinks;
7. Disable All WordPress Updates (T_T господи вобще хз зачем это ставили);
8. Rel Canonical;
9. RSS for Yandex Turbo;
10. Webcraftic Clearfy - disable unused features;
11. WordPress HTTPS;
12. WP-Optimize;
13. WP-Sweep.

Comment: Что -то у вас ваш `.htaccess` попахивает не пониманием того как вообще должны формироваться редиректы. Множественное перенаправление с оной страницы на другую, и там у вас и происходит циклическая зависимость. Сами посмотрите откуда и куда ведут ваши редиректы. Все возвращается к одному и тому же.

Comment: @llenn Прошелся по редиректам, то ли глаз замылился то ли что, вроде все в норме, некоторые редиректы с кирилицы на латинские урлы, некоторые просто переехавшие ссылки, вроде как самих на себя нет.